# How to keep results within the same row in a time punch in and out system?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a simple bed time and get up time sheet. The custom app script links to the buttons and the punchIn function is connected to the Bedtime button while the punchOut function is connected to the Get Up button. The bedtime should go into column b and the Get Up time should go into column e. However, it seems that the values alternate instead of going on the same row. I think this happens because of the getNextRow function, and more specifically the .getLastRow method. Instead of alternating (sheet link is down below) it should stay in the same row.

Also, is there any way to freeze the button? It is a drawing, not an image, so it seems like there isn't a way to attach it a cell in order for it to be frozen.

Finally I need to make it so the bedtimes and get up times only alternate if there is a difference between the previous date and the current date. For example, if I forgot to hit the bedtime button at night, but remembered to hit in the morning, it should be able to recognize that there is a missing bedtime and skip over that bedtime and move onto the next row and place the new times correctly. (I will explain this part in more detail if needed/There is an example in the sheet)

Overview:

- Fix alternation from .getLastRow method. (Maybe there is a .getLastRow in cell method?)
- Freeze button to first row even though it is a drawing, not image
- Move onto next row when there is a missing bedtime
- Help is appreciated! Thanks so much!

Here is the google sheets link and my code:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1db4_PpK5yV8exM-HuGHzoZ3SpXjZKQuHdGygedNitEw/edit?usp=sharing

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}

function addBedTime(a) {
  //let row = 13
  var row = getNextRow();
  if (getValue('b' + row) == '') {
    setValue('b' + row, a);
    //row += 1 
  }
}

function addGetUpTime(a) {
  //let row = 13
  var row = getNextRow();
  if (getValue('e' + row) == '') {
    setValue('e' + row, a)
    //row +=1
  }
}

function punchIn() {
  addBedTime(new Date());
}

function punchOut() {
  addGetUpTime(new Date());
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that `I need to make it so the bedtimes and get up times only alternate if there is a difference between the previous date and the current date`, I'm using the hidden `A` column to store dates as key of this data set.

Just keep in mind that if in your use case you can have multiple bedtimes on the same day, you will need to change this implementation.

Additionally, it is not possible to "freeze" a Drawing object to a cell in Sheets unfortunately. If you want to workaround that, consider rendering your [own sidebar using HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or even [adding a custom top menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms)

See my implementation below:

#### Sample Code:

```js
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getTodayRowNumber() {
  var todayRow = findTodayRow(); // Find/create Today's row
  return todayRow.getRowIndex(); // Return Today's row index
}

function addBedTime(a) {
  //let row = 2
  var row = getTodayRowNumber();
  if (getValue('b' + row) == '') {
    setValue('b' + row, a);
    //row += 1 
  }
}

function addGetUpTime(a) {
  //Assuming the get up time is always entryDate+1, then
  //Get Up time should check if last entry is blank
  //If true, add Get Up Time on the last entry row 
  //Otherwise, insert your logic for this scenario

  var row = getTodayRowNumber() - 1; //Get previous entry row number
  row = (row > 1) ? row : 2; //Bug fix in case there is only headers in the sheet

  if (getValue('e' + row) == '') { //only change column E if it is blank
    setValue('e' + row, a)
    //row +=1
  }
}

function punchIn() {
  addBedTime(new Date());
}

function punchOut() {
  addGetUpTime(new Date());
}

function findTodayRow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Initiating opened Spreadsheet
  var ws = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Getting active Worksheet in opened Spreadsheet
  var dataRange = ws.getDataRange(); //Getting used range of cells

  var lastLoggedDay = dataRange.getCell(dataRange.getLastRow(), 1).getValue(); //getting last A column from used range
  lastLoggedDay = (lastLoggedDay) ? lastLoggedDay : (new Date(0)); //Fixing scenario where Column A is blank
  lastLoggedDay.setHours(0,0,0,0); //clearing time for later date comparison

  var today = (new Date()); //getting today's date
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0); //clearing time for later date comparison
    
  if(today.getTime() == lastLoggedDay.getTime()){ 
    //if the last logged day is same as today, then return the Row Range for today

    return ws.getRange("A" + String(dataRange.getLastRow()) + ":" + String(dataRange.getLastRow()));

  } else {
    //if the last logged day is NOT the same as today, 
      //then "create" a new row and 
      //put today's date in hidden Column A, 
      //then return the newly created Row Range for today

    var newRow = ws.getRange("A" + String(dataRange.getLastRow()+1) + ":" + String(dataRange.getLastRow()+1));
    newRow.getCell(1, 1).setValue(today); //getting first cell of today's range (should be hidden Date column)

    return newRow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I copied your code down, but I get an error when clicking the buttons. It says, "TypeError: lastLoggedDay.setHours is not a function". I researched the .setHours method, and it seems like it is a function and you used it properly too. Not sure how the error occured

Comment: Ahh my bad, haven't treated the scenario where Column `A` is completely blank. In this case, `lastLoggedDay` will return `undefined` which don't have a setHours() method.
Fixed the code on my answer to treat this scenario. Let me know if it works for you. Cheers!

Comment: "Just keep in mind that if in your use case you can have multiple bedtimes on the same day, you will need to change this implementation." In my use case, it is possible to have multiple bedtimes on the same day. Honestly, when I said "I need to make it so the bedtimes and get up times only alternate if there is a difference between the previous date and the current date," it made my question more confusing to answer. I need to make it so the getup time can also go on the same day as the bedtime. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Also, I accidentally made my sheet link viewer only. Did you make a copy of the sheet and test it out? Again, thanks for helping me out, I am not familiar with the app script functions, and your knowledge is way more than mine.

Comment: Either way, I changed it so you can edit the sheet.

Comment: `Did you make a copy of the sheet and test it out?` -- Yep, I've created one from scratch with similar data structure. 

So, my understanding now is: 
- addBedTime() will always create a new entry (row) regardless and populate Bed time cell with current Date/time
- addGetUpTime() will check if last logged entry has Get Up time cell populated, if it is, it will create a new entry (row) and populate Get Up time cell with current Date/time. if it is NOT populated, fill last logged entry Get Up time cell with current Date/time.

Can you confirm if that's correct?